# Number of non-isomorphic representations of a Lie group

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let *G* be a compact Lie group. Suppose that it has a discrete center. Then, I want to show that there are only finitely many non isomorphic representations of *G* for a given dimension.

I feel like the way to go is by contradiction using Schur’s lemma. I would like some help, I’m really stuck.

Comment: I think it's more difficult than a bare application of Schur's lemma.

Comment: Do you have any hint ?

Comment: Even if standard it's really harder than "exercise-level", as far as I know. I'd suggest to study a book, for instance Brocker/Dieck, Compact Lie groups. Roughly, one approach is: one can suppose $G$ simply connected; then the set of reps in dimension $n$ is the set of Lie algebra homomorphisms (which forms an affine algebraic variety), and then show that each connected component (of the set of real points) consists of a single conjugacy class of representations.

Comment: This boils down to a vanishing theorem for $H^1(G, V_\pi)$ (continuous cohomology),  where  $V_\pi$ is a finite-dimensional linear representation of $G$. The vanishing of   $H^1(G, V)$ amounts to proving that every affine action of $G$ on $V$ has a fixed point, which is an application of the barycenter construction. I can write down details for this answer but I suspect that this will be incomprehensible at this point of your study of Lie groups.

Comment: Weyl dimension formula maybe ?